# Search and show data at the same time Django

Tags: django, search, dynamic

What I want:
As we generally see on e-commerce site like say amazon. we search some keywords, then it loads the data but "one by one". for example, I searched a t-shirt. it first display a tshirt while other are in loading process, and then other gets loaded one by one then more are loading in the next line.
It is like dynamic search along with dynamic user display.

I want to achieve this in my django website.

What I got to know after a lot search.
-- elasticsearch is very good for searching data
--* but what if I want to display my complete data of a model, but lets say 50 items on a page then 50 on next page so on. all items and their images are being loaded dynamically one by one.

How can I achieve this "one by one display thing". Please suggest me some keywords to google it. Or guide me through the process.

"or"

is it an automatic process??

like once we can get all 50 items data and its images link in one Ajax request then, attaching DOM elements via for loop will load images one by one.

"or"

process 5 (just a random number) Ajax request one after another each fetching 10 dataset. and in the result of each Ajax request, we can run for loop to attach those 10 datasets and their images link in DOM elements.

"or"

this is not automatic, and requires an backend and front end implementation both.